# Update SQL Server column with reference to the another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, calculation

I have two tables. Table1:
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ag0q.png)
Table2:
[image]

I want to update the `income` column in Table1 with the reference of Table2.

Example #1: if the `income_target` column of Table2 is "25" and 25 is in the Period2, I want Table1 to be summed with Table1 (Period1 + Period2)

Example #2: if the `income_target` column of Table2 is "40" and 40 is in the Period4, I want Table1 to be summed with Table1(Period1+Period2+period3+Period4)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: The fact you have multiple period and income columns Looks like a design flaw.

Comment: i have updated the table one with right column names

Comment: table1 "income" column is the output

Comment: check out this article on how to update with joins. https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-update-join/